# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to data class

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to get the data from firebase. I tried 2 methods 1st methods give me Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to data class error. The second return null although the datasnapshot has values.
1st method:

```
database.getReference("Customers").child(custID).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            it.children.forEach() {
                var cust = it.getValue(DataClassCustomer::class.java)//Error
                custName = cust?.firstName + " " + cust?.lastName
            }
        }
```

The Error:

```
2021-03-12 00:25:39.634 28929-28929/com.example.goldenbeachhotelmanagementsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.goldenbeachhotelmanagementsystem, PID: 28929
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.goldenbeachhoteldataclasses.DataClassCustomer
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.example.goldenbeachhotelmanagementsystem.RoomManagement$readCustData$1.onSuccess(RoomManagement.kt:243)
        at com.example.goldenbeachhotelmanagementsystem.RoomManagement$readCustData$1.onSuccess(RoomManagement.kt:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here's the data class:

```
data class DataClassCustomer(
    var email: String? = "", var firstName:String? = "", var ic:String? = "", var lastName:String? ="", var phone:String?= ""){

}
```

2nd method:
I tried to use without loop but the cust value will be null

```
database.getReference("Customers").child(custID).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                var cust = it.getValue(DataClassCustomer::class.java)
                custName = cust?.firstName + " " + cust?.lastName
                println(custName)
        }
```

The debug output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV0Xs.png)

Firebase Customers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjMI6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.goldenbeachhoteldataclasses.DataClassCustomer

Because you are trying to convert String objects to DataClassCustomer objects, which is actually not possible in Java. This is happening because you are using the following reference:

```
database.getReference("Customers").child(custID)
```

That points to the **C0001** node. When using the forEach() loop, you are getting all children within that object, which are actually Strings and **not** "DataClassCustomer" objects, hence that error. If you want to get all "DataClassCustomer" objects that exist within the "Customers" node, then simply remove the call to `.child(custID)` and your code will work perfectly fine. If you want to get the values of "email", "firstName", "ic", "lastName" and "phone", then replace the following line:

```
var cust = it.getValue(DataClassCustomer::class.java)
```

with:

```
var cust = it.getValue(String::class.java)
```